# How can i change Form1.Text when its Opened with a button on Form2

Tags: c#

I have 2 form and I want change Form1.Text when its run with a button on
 Form2 !!!! I dont whant make a instance Form1.
 Thanks friends**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 F2 = new Form2();
        F2.ShowDialog();
    }
}


public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ChangeForm1Text_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case (you need a reference to the Owner form) there is a simple shorcut that doesn't require to keep a local instance of the first form

Just pass the instance of Form1 as the Owner in the ShowDialog call

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 F2 = new Form2();
    F2.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Now you could reference the property Owner inside the Form2 code

```
private void ChangeForm1Text_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Owner.Text = "your new caption for form1";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way for you to do this is to pass the instance of `Form1` into a constructor on Form2`. So add this constructor and field to Form2:

```
private readonly Form1 _parentForm1;
public Form2(Form1 parentForm1) : this()
{
    _parentForm1 = parentForm1;
}
```

Now when you create your Form2 in the button click, create it like this:

```
Form2 F2 = new Form2(this);
F2.ShowDialog();
```

Then you can use `_parentForm1` anywhere in your instance of Form2 to refer back to the other form.