# How can i run Button1.PerformClick() in Form1 with a Button on Form2 when two forms are opened

Tags: c#

I have 2 Form and i want run Button1.PerformClick() in form1 with button2 in form2, when two forms are opened !!!

I dont want make a instance Form1.

Thanks friends

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonShowForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 F2 = new Form2();
        F2.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //Run my method...
    }
}



public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ClickButton1Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 //Run my method... |Form1.Button1.PerformClick() 

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to read about events and delegates

Comment: Please don't repost the same question! If you habe follow-up questions put it with your [first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344006/how-can-i-change-form1-text-when-its-opened-with-a-button-on-form2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Form2` needs a reference to an instance of `Form1` and needs to invoke the functionality on that instance.

Create a method on `Form1` which invokes this functionality:

```
public void PerformButton1Click()
{
    Button1.PerformClick();
}
```

Require an instance of `Form1` on the constructor for `Form2`:

```
private Form1 Form1Instance { get; set; }

public Form2(Form1 form1Instance)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Form1Instance = form1Instance;
}
```

Pass a reference to the existing instance when constructing an instance of `Form2`:

```
Form2 F2 = new Form2(this);
F2.ShowDialog();
```

Then you can invoke that functionality on that instance:

```
private void ClickButton1Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1Instance.PerformButton1Click();
}
```